# Is there API to build WebApi route from [RoutePrefix] and [Route] attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi application with a bunch of controllers and methods tagged with `[RoutePrefix]` and `[Route]` attributes. I would like to collect all such methods via reflection and inform the client side with all WebApi calls that are supported by server.

My goal is to inform the front-end with the list of available API for the logged-in user so that front-end could hide the controls for the methods that are not allowed.

I wrote a simple code that does the job.

```
// GET api/systeminfo/allowedapi
[HttpGet]
[Route("allowedapi")]
[ResponseType(typeof(WebApiCollectionDto))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllowedApi()
{
    List<string> apiList = new List<string>();

    Type baseControllerType = typeof(ApiController);
    IEnumerable<Type> controllerTypes = GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(item => baseControllerType.IsAssignableFrom(item));

    foreach (Type controllerType in controllerTypes)
    {
        RoutePrefixAttribute routePrefixAttribute = controllerType.GetCustomAttribute<RoutePrefixAttribute>();

        IEnumerable<MethodInfo> apiMethods = controllerType.GetMethods();

        foreach (MethodInfo apiMethod in apiMethods)
        {
            RouteAttribute routeAttribute = apiMethod.GetCustomAttribute<RouteAttribute>();
            if (routeAttribute == null) // not an api method
                continue;

            string routeTemplate = routeAttribute.Template;
            if (routeTemplate.StartsWith("~"))
                apiList.Add(routeTemplate.Substring(1));
            else
                apiList.Add(String.Format("/{0}/{1}", routePrefixAttribute.Prefix, routeTemplate));
        }
    }

    WebApiCollectionDto result = new WebApiCollectionDto(apiList);
    return await Task.FromResult(Ok(result));
}
```

My concern is that this implementation is a bit naive. To make this code production-ready I need to write additional processing for '/' character at the beginning and at the end of the template. So may be there is an implementation that I could reuse out of the box?

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at swagger http://swagger.io/ and a webapi integration https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

Comment: jure, great hint! I've started looking at Swashbuckle and it appeared that internally they use Miscrosoft API called IApiExplorer. So basically this is the answer to the question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is API from Miscrosoft that does the job. `System.Web.Http.Description.IApiExplorer`

[ASP.NET Web API: Introducing IApiExplorer/ApiExplorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/05/13/asp-net-web-api-introducing-iapiexplorer-apiexplorer.aspx)

And a much cleaner implementation of the code above:

```
// GET api/systeminfo/allowedapi
[HttpGet]
[Route("allowedapi")]
[ResponseType(typeof (WebApiCollectionDto))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllowedApi()
{
    List<string> apiList = new List<string>();

    IApiExplorer apiExplorer = Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();

    foreach (ApiDescription apiDescription in apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions)
        apiList.Add(apiDescription.RelativePath);

    WebApiCollectionDto result = new WebApiCollectionDto(apiList);
    return await Task.FromResult(Ok(result));
}
```